# Must a complex power series *fail* to be convergent somewhere on its circle of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis

My textbook asserts so, but I can't find its proof of the claim. On the other hand, a lecture slide I'm cross-referencing claims that a power series is allowed to be convergent at ALL points of its circle of convergence.

So who is correct?

Comment: It fails to converge where it hits a non-correctable singularity, where the function has no value.

Comment: I think the power series for $\sqrt {z+1}$ should converge on all of $S^1$, but it cannot extend beyond $z=-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @N.S. demonstrated, the power series itself can converge at every point of the circle of convergence. The correct statement is that the *function* represented by the power series on the interior of the disk of convergence must have a singularity at (at least) one point of the circle. That is, it cannot be analytically continued to give an analytic function on a larger disk. For, if it could, the radius of convergence would have to be larger.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that

$$\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

is convergent everywhere on the circle of convergence. This follows immediately from the triangle inequality and the convergence of $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Convergence_on_the_boundary. What happens "just outside" the compact disk of convergence?

Comment: I was thinking to the same one. This is absolutely convergent for |x|=1, hence it must be convergent.